# Create react app not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed nodejs and npm using sudo apt-get. But when i try to install create-react-app using sudo npm install -g create-react-app, i get an error that addLocal could not install.

Comment: Did you try `npx create-react-app my-app` like the [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)?

Comment: Try `npm install -g npm@latest`. It should fix the error.

Comment: @Thierry Joel what problem are you facing , can you mention?

Comment: @AkshayGulhane You should not [install it globally](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started), OP probably following an outdated article.